# How to destroy dropdzonejs?

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

How to destroy dropdzonejs?

When I have SPA and leave the page, I want to clean up so it does not listen to body events anymore.

Answer (score 13):

```
myDropzone.destroy();
```

I swear I had the same problem and I'll find that with a
lucky attempt... it works!

Answer (score 2):

I removed `removedfile()` function from Dropzone options and `myDropzone.destroy();` worked for me.

Comment: Why did you have to remove the `removedfile()` function from the DropZone options? I have this function, and the `.destroy()` or `.disable()` function work out-of-the-box (tested with DropZone 5.x and 6.x).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/methods):

> If you do not need a dropzone anymore, just call `.disable()` on the
> object. This will remove all event listeners on the element, and clear
> all file arrays. To reenable a Dropzone use `.enable()`

If you initialize dropzone like:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzoneid", { url: "/some/url"});
```

You should be able to disable it with:

```
myDropzone.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following methods : The `destroy()` and `disable()` methods both exist, and they seem to act the exact same way.

In fact, DropZone does not have a real destruction method. These methods will "put the instance in pause" (what is, by design, the closest implementation of a DropZone instance destruction).

This applies to DropZone 5.x and DropZone 6.x (try `myDropzone.disable()` or `myDropzone.destroy()` in the console on this v6.x example page https://www.dropzone.dev/bootstrap.html) : The DropZone instance will be disabled, thus leading to the "**Add Files...**" button being inoperative.

The instance can then be re-enabled by calling `myDropzone.enable()`.

---

PS : DropZone switch from v5 to v6 in 2021-2022. The website was completely revamped and screwed-up: the documentation is partial, incomplete, too short.

If you still need to access the excellent and exhaustive v5 documentation, you can head up to the obvious Web Archive Wayback machine ! Here is the very latest v5 documentation page https://web.archive.org/web/20210829160314/https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want destroy all dropzone instances just add if (Dropzone.instances.length > 0) Dropzone.instances.forEach(dz => dz.destroy()) to document ready.